Degree of extension in infinite field
In a certain exercise I have been asked to find the degree of the extension $[\mathbb{F}_7(t):\mathbb{F}_7(t^2)]$, as well as a basis of the extension. I'm not given any extra piece of information, so I guess that $t$ is a variable and the fields above are polynomial fields. If it isn't like that, then the following reasoning is probably wrong, so I hope that with my hypothesis they are fields. However, here is my argument:

$t \notin \mathbb{F}_7(t^2)$ and it satisfies $p(x) = x^2-t^2 \in \mathbb{F}_7(t^2)[x]$, so it is irreducible and with $t^2$ as root, therefore the degree of the extension is $2$. The problem comes when trying to give a basis. My intuition tells me that it can be $\{1,t \}$ since each element in the bigger field (supposing it is actually) is generated by multiplying and adding with $(t^2)^n$ the linear combinations of the basis $\{1,t \}$. Is this reasoning right? I have also been asked to find $t^{-1}$ and $(t+1)^{-1}$, writing them as linear combinations of the basis. Could somebody help me?

Btw, $\mathbb{F}_7$ is the finite field with $7$ elements, if you want, $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$.

If you have two fields $K$ and $K(\alpha)$ and know the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $m$ of degree $k$, then $1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{k-1}$ is a basis of $K(\alpha)$ over $K$.
Writing $1/t=0\cdot 1+\frac{1}{t^2}\cdot t$ gives the first linear combintation. The second I'll leave to you.

But, is $\frac{1}{t^2}$ an element of any of the fields?

Well yeah, it is in $\mathbb{F}_7(t^2)$

This is the field of rational functions, not just polynomials.

Thanks for your answers, indeed, I forgot that division was possible.
